# Endless fetching of assets using rails with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a Rails 4 app along with twitter bootstrap. For some reason, whenever I open a modal the assets in heroku are fetched constantly. I am not precompiling assets since I am using the 'rails_12factor' gem provided for Rails 4.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening and a fix?

Thanks!

Comment: We need to see some more of your code. Do you have any ajax or anything that might be refreshing on your page?

Comment: [link](http://groopanda.herokuapp.com) is a demo of the site. The problem seems to occur mainly after using one of the sidebars on the left. I am making an async call to fetch show page on the modal.